# How to iterate certain sets of statements in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to iterate these statements number of times...say 100:

```
z=0.005;
num= xlsread(filename);
t=num./z;
t1=t/10;
m=num-(z*t1)
xlswrite(filename,m);
```

Actually I am reading one excel file, modifying it and storing it into same excel file. I need to do it iteratively.

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop? For example:

```
for i=1:100
   disp(i)
end
```

will print 1 to 100, iterating through what you've given the for loop. In your case, replace `disp(i)` with your code and the appropriate filename that may depend on the loop iteration variable.

Comment: This has got to be the simplest answer I've seen for a long time.

Comment: He asked a somewhat general question and got a somewhat general answer. Sounds like what the OP wants though ;)